# I want to send my location to the server each 1 minute even the app in the background in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, background-task

what is the best practice to call method each 1 minute even the app in the background(android),
I am using Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) to do  it in forground but I need to call method even the app in the background

```
private fun runScheduleMethods() {
    mainHandler.post(object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            viewModel.loadCurrentLocation(locationRequest)
            mainHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000 * 60)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use foreground service with notification(because if notification is active then android OS will not kill it)

here is blog
good luck..!

https://medium.com/@ramkumarv3/foreground-service-with-notification-channel-ac6697c8a6d1